# Apache2.4のアクセス制限について

Tags: apache

Ubuntu16.04でapacheのPHPをFastCGIで動かしたかったので、fcgidモジュールを導入しました。しかし設定ファイルで下記のように記述すると403が返ってきて、期待通り動作しませんでした。

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AddHandler fcgid-script .php
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    FcgidWrapper /usr/lib/cgi-bin/php7.0 .php
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Order...の部分を下記のように変更すると、期待通りFastCGIが動作しました。

```
# Order allow,deny
# Allow from all
Require all granted
```

mod-access_compatを有効にしていれば、上記の2つの設定は同じ意味合い(全て許可)になるという認識だったのですが、完全に同じ意味ではないということでしょうか？

なせOrder...による指定の場合403エラーとなるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

/etc/apache2/apache2.conf の157行目で `Require all denied` が指定されているのが原因のようです。

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>
```

この設定により、 `/usr/lib/cgi-bin` に `Allow from all` を指定しても、その上の階層である `/` に `Require all denied` が指定されているので、そちらが優先されるようです。

例えばこの `Require all denied` をコメントアウトすると 200 を返すようになります。

Comment: なるほど。Requireによる指定だと上書きできるのに、Orderだと上書きできないんですね。mod-access_compatを指定していても、RequireとOrderの指定を混在させちゃうとよくなさそうですね。